# How do I make sleep/wait on Rust without std?

Tags: rust, operating-system

I'm trying to make OS that does VGA text animation thing, but it's really fast as it processes as fast as it can.

So I wanna make the "wait" function and wait like 100ms each motions but I have no idea how to make it without using std crate.

So the question, how do I make sleep/wait on Rust without std?

Thanks

Comment: I realize that this may not be a true answer to the question but don't forget you can always look at how it's implemented in std: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/thread/mod.rs.html#803-805

Comment: @JaredSmith std relies on the OS primitives, which is not really an option when your program is the OS.

Comment: What hardware is your program running on? The answer might depend on what kind of timing primitives are available

Comment: Something to look into is async/await on embedded systems.

Comment: @harmic qemu x86-64 on intel x64 cpu.

Comment: You could set up a timer interrupt handler that does the drawing periodically and have it pull data from a structure in memory set by the main loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the processor clock with the `rdtsc` instruction and do a `hlt` loop until the required time passes. Or you can read the CMOS clock, but that will only have a second resolution.